# Devise Mont Carlo and Las Vegas Algorithms to Solve Maximum Independent Set

Tags: algorithms, graphs, monte-carlo

I am trying to devise a Las Vegas algorithm to solve [Maximum Independent Set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)), but I don't know how to start.

Also, I want to devise a Mont Carlo algorithm for this problem.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Maximum Independent Set in an NP-hard optimization problem. You are unlikely to find any kind of efficient algorithm that always works.

Comment: I know it, but I want to devise a randomized algorithm anyway. @YuvalFilmus

Comment: The acronym MIS is usually used to indicate *maximal* independent set, is that what you mean or indeed maximum?

Comment: Yes, I mean Maximum Independent Set. @kviiri

Comment: What's the context in which you encountering this?  What is the motivation for this task?  It is trivial to construct an exponential-time algorithm if you don't care about its running time. What is preventing you from doing that?  What progress have you made?

Comment: Toss $n$ coins. Then run an exhaustive search algorithm. If you want the algorithm to depend on the coin tosses, use the coin tosses to choose an order on the vertices.

Comment: This is too big a question for a single post. You need to break down the problem into smaller pieces. If you don't know how to approach that, that's always a good hint to do some reading and/or experimenting.

Comment: An Independent Set S on a graph G is a Clique of the same size on the complementary graph. Try figuring out if it's easier to think about cliques rather than IS :)

Comment: Can you explain how to run an exhaustive search precisely? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: They are equal. So, VC is as hard as IS. @VashTheStampede

Comment: I think your answer may be correct. If it is possible, please explain more. Thank you @YuvalFilmus

Comment: An exhaustive search algorithm just tried all possible solutions one by one.

Comment: @SepehrOmidvar I know. What I was saying is that maybe it's easier *for you* to find a Las Vegas for Clique than for IS. Problems are equally hard, but humans think with intuition not always with hardness.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. How about the Mont Carlo version? What should we do in this case? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: You already have a Monte Carlo algorithm. It happens not to make any mistakes.